# How do you find the height of something inside a circle?

Tags: geometry, circles

Say you had a circle r=5 and it is on a graph (just to simplify things) so that the centre of the circle is at the origin. If I was to pick any x axis, how would I know what are the two y co-ordinates of the circle.

Comment: Can you post an Image please?

Comment: sure. UN minute S'il vous plaît. (Yeah, I'm not actually french)

Comment: Use $x^2+y^2=r^2$ to get the $y$ values for a given $x$ value

Comment: $y = \pm\sqrt{5^2-x^2}$  Pas de problème !

Comment: Erm thanks. May I just say, can you put this in an answer so I can close it please

Comment: This is done!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OP's request, I post my comment as an answer. $$y = \pm \sqrt{5^2-x^2} = \pm \sqrt{25 - x^2}$$